# Cannot initialize submodule (branch of private repository)

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

Please observe that I have two branches in a private repository: master and content, the latter being a submoudle of  the former -

[image]

`git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/vishvAsa/rahaShTippanyaH.git` succeds just fine - except for the submodule content.

The below fails as well:

```
git submodule update --init --remote                                                                 ✔  5m 9s  
Cloning into '/home/vvasuki/gitland/vishvAsa/rahaShTippanyaH/content'...
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "vishvas.vasuki@gmail.com" from agent: agent refused operation
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

But the error mentioned does not make sense since I was able to clone the exact same private repository without the `content` submodule. Further `ssh-add -l` shows an rss key.

Is this a github bug? How to fix? (Switching submodule upstream to `https://github.com/vishvAsa/rahaShTippanyaH.git` or `https://vvasuki@github.com/vishvAsa/rahaShTippanyaH.git` did not help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to the HTTPS URL should have helped, since the initial clone succeeds.

But try and set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'
```

That way, you will see which key is tried for this clone.
Check also that `ssh -Tv git@github.com` does return `Hi vvasuki! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`
As long as this first check does not succeed, any SSH URL would fail.

Comment: Thanks! Setting `url = https://github.com/vishvAsa/rahaShTippanyaH.git` worked (strange I vaguely recalled trying that earlier and failing).